# UITableView -reloadSectionIndexTitles not calling data source

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a `UISearchBar` within a `UITableView`, which behaves like the one in the "Artists" tab of the iPod application.

I have it hiding the navigation bar, and resizing the search box to show the "Cancel" button, etc. but am unable to get it to hide the section index titles.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  inSearchMode_ = YES; // tell sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: to return nil
  tableView_.scrollEnabled = NO; // works correctly, var is definitely wired
  [tableView_ reloadSectionIndexTitles]; // doesn't call sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:
  ...
```

Am I missing something? Is `UITableView -reloadSectionIndexTitles` broken?

Typically my response to this kind of thing would be to call `reloadData`, but that has the side effect of causing the `UISearchBar` to lose focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what I need to do is to use a `UISearchDisplayController` rather than hand-rolling my own. I was able to modify the "TableSearch" sample to use sections and section headings, and it behaves as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

I think approach you want is along these lines (Say you have a ArtistController which you want to make searchable):

- Add a sub-controller to the ArtistController called ArtistSearchController
- When the search box is clicked, bring the ArtistSearchController to the front as modal (to hide artists) or add transparency if you still want to show artists in the background.
- When a search term is entered, created a model for the ArtistSearchController which is the data from ArtistController, filtered using the search term, and then display it in a list view
- close the modal view when the user hits cancel.

This will save you from manipulating your original controller/nav bar and give it better usability

Comment: That sounds very much like the way UISearchDisplayController operates, now I've played with the sample.